# Unity greeter startup script on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synergy, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-14.04

So what I want to do is run a script on startup that starts the synergy daemon. I want it to run automagically when the system starts in GUI mode even if no one actually logs in. I have a script for this but in the past it was run from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`. This doesn't do the trick since I upgraded today to Trusty Tahir.

What is the Trusty Tahir equivalent to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`?

Update: The above is apparently the wrong question. It *is* launching but it drops dead whereas it did not before.  Investigation ongoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hunch and because this system is so ridiculously fast (It's one of those custom gamer boxes ), I added a 5 second sleep to the script.  This fixed the issue. I was able to cut it to 3 seconds later on.

The reason for this is actually pretty simple. The system is so fast that it is fully operational with the Unity greeter fully displayed long before the network interface comes online. No network, no synergy and no ssh.